# Disable CSRF validation for individual actions in Yii2

Tags: csrf, yii2

Is there a way to disable CSRF validation for some actions of the controller keeping it enabled for the other ones?

In my case I have several configurable Action classes, that are intended to be injected into controllers. I can't pass csrf validation token into the AJAX request because the thing I'm working with is external (made not by me) WYSIWYG plugin at the frontend. Yes, I can still disable csrf validation of the whole controller using these actions, but it may be insecure.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

For the specific controller / actions you can disable CSRF validation like so:

```
use Yii;

...

Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

Or inside a controller:

```
$this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

Take a look at [$enableCsrfValidation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#$enableCsrfValidation-detail) property of [yii\web\Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html).

**Update:**

Here is some specification.

If you want to disable CSRF validation for individual action(s) you need to do it in `beforeAction` event handler because CSRF token is checked before action runs (in `beforeAction` of `yii\web\Controller`).

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeAction($action)
{            
    if ($action->id == 'my-method') {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

**Official docs:**

- [beforeAction()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#beforeAction%28%29-detail)

Comment: Checking of this parameter is processing in beforeAction, so it would be useless to do this inside of action.

Comment: @yujin1st I actually didn't mention anything about where exactly to place it, but yes, it's needed to be placed in `beforeAction`. Thanks for remark, updated the answer.

Comment: but I had used your code exactly as you had it replacing with the action

Comment: The `$action` should already contain action id, try to `var_dump` it inside the method, what's the result?

Comment: it gave me an array where the action id I was look for was `$action['id']`, but when I tried to use that it gave me some error saying I couldn't use `$action` as an array.

Comment: Please edit $action == 'my-method' on $action->id == 'my-method'

Comment: @Alex Thanks for remark, corrected the answer. By the way, you can suggest edit too.

Answer (score 9):

For me this is what worked

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    if($action->id == 'my-action') {
        Yii::$app->request->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: need use "==" no "="

Comment: @haiflive "===" and not "=="

Answer (score 6):

Put this inside your controller, just replace index with whatever action you want to disable `csrf` on.

```
public function beforeAction()
{      
    if ($this->action->id == 'index') {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: why using long route `Yii::$app->controller->` when you are in the controller use `$this` for disabling for the current controller action..

Answer (score 4):

i have tried this and it worked .

Go to the specific controller and write this at the top.

```
public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

Comment: This disables CSRF validation for ALL actions in the controller. OP asked about individual actions.