# CKEditor file upload not working in Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor, yii2

I'm working on Yii2 Project where I've integrated http://ckeditor.com/demo

Now I want to implement functionality of file/image upload in it.

This is how I integrated CKEditor in Yii2 Project.

**Step1: AppAsset.php**

```
public $js = [
    'ckeditor/ckeditor.js',
];
```

Calling ckeditor.js javascript file from `config/AppAsset` Class

**Step2: View**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'standard_output_information')->textarea(['rows' => 2, 'class'=>'ckeditor']) ?>
```

**Step3: config.js**

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {   
    var base_url = window.location.origin;
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    var projectUrl = base_url + "/" + pathArray[1] + "/" + pathArray[2] + "/" + pathArray[3] + "/uploads";

    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = base_url + "/pcwf" + "/backend" + "/web" + "/businessprocessprofile" + "/upload";
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = base_url + "/pcwf" + "/backend" + "/web" + "/businessprocessprofile" + "/upload";    
};
```

Here I've configured ImageBrowserUrl and ImageUploadUrl mentioned here http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_(Uploader)

**Step4: Controller**

```
public function actionUpload() {
    echo \yii\helpers\Html::csrfMetaTags();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    exit;
}
```

Here I'm expecting uploaded image data. But whenever I click on `Send it to Server` button after selection of an image its giving me following error.

[image]

Not sure whether its issue of wrong url configuration in config.js or is it Yii2 form submission issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have a problem with the CRSF tokens. Read more about the security here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-best-practices.html. The easiest way to get around this is to disable CRSF for that particular action. You can take a look on how to do that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28526946/1880627

Comment: Thanks... it worked for me. I just inherited beforeAction method in my controller and disabled csrf token and it worked like charm...  :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than disabling CSRF validation it is far better and more secure to submit the token with the form to pass server-side validation. This can be quite easily done by injecting a hidden input field into the upload form with javascript:

```
$(document).off('click', '.cke_dialog_tabs a[id^="cke_Upload_"]').on('click', '.cke_dialog_tabs a[id^="cke_Upload_"]', function () {
    var $forms = $('.cke_dialog_ui_input_file iframe').contents().find('form');
    var csrfName = yii.getCsrfParam();
    $forms.each(function () {
        if (!$(this).find('input[name=' + csrfName + ']').length) {
            var csrfTokenInput = $('<input/>').attr({
                'type': 'hidden',
                'name': csrfName
            }).val(yii.getCsrfToken());
            $(this).append(csrfTokenInput);
        }
    });
});
```

For a more detailed discussion on the issue refer to [2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget, issue #2](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget/issues/2). This is also where the code snippet is taken from, with a few minor tweaks to cover the case of multiple widgets on the page.