# Yii2 post form can't execute the action

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a form which I trigger with `jQuery trigger` and if I set the method to `GET` it works. But if the method is 'POST' - `400 Bad Request`.
My view looks like:

```
<?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')): ?>
    <div class="success-message text-center"><?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success') ?></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <form action="/order/confirmation" method="post" style="display: none" id="confirm-order">
        <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?= $_GET['id'] ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="confirm" value="1"/>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
$this->registerJs("
    (function(){
        let form = $('#confirm-order')       
        form.trigger('submit')
    })()
", \yii\web\View::POS_LOAD)
?>
```

And my action is:

```
public function actionConfirmation()
    {
        $id = Yii::$app->request->post('order_id');
        $confirm = Yii::$app->request->post('confirm');
        if($confirm){
            $order = Orders::findOne(['id' => $id]);
            $order->confirmed = 1;
            $order->update(false);
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app', 'Your personal information was deleted'));
        }
        return $this->render('confirmation');
    }
```

In my `UrlManager` the URL is set like this:

```
'order/confirmation' => 'order/confirmation',
```

Also tried to put `behaviors` to the controller action like:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'confirmation'  => ['POST', 'GET'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Nothing helps. Summary - `GET` works. `POST` do not. What is my mistake here?

Comment: I see that you are not sending CSRF, that it is magically created using ActiveForm. If you don't want to use CSRF, disable it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526873/disable-csrf-validation-for-individual-actions-in-yii2)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to XSS, `$_GET['id']` should be encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add input with CSRF token manually, like below, into your form as you are not using the `ActiveForm` which add the hidden input automatically to submit the `POST` request and all the `POST` requests require the `CSRF` token for preventing [CSRF attacks](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), so I don't recommend you to disable it but you should provide the input manually:

```
<form action="/order/confirmation" method="post" style="display: none" id="confirm-order">
    <?= \yii\helpers\Html::hiddenInput(Yii::$app->request->csrfParam, Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken());?>
    <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?= \yii\helpers\Html::encode($_GET['id']) ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="confirm" value="1"/>
</form>
```