# Yii2 Bad Request 400 - Unable to login from iframe on another domain

Tags: iframe, yii2, cross-domain, csrf, csrf-token

I am using iframe on domain1.com
And the yii2 web app is on domain2.com

I am have passed domain.com url in the src of iframe on domain1.com
and use this in the yii2 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to enable cors

I can login on domain2.com but it throws bad request 400 error if I try logging in through iframe on domain1.com

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: you might need to turn off `enableCsrfProtection`

Comment: your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526873/disable-csrf-validation-for-individual-actions-in-yii2

Comment: both of these were not the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question, I solved the problem

- Change the PHP version to >7.3
- Go into the config/web.php for basic app or config/main.php
- Add this: `'httpOnly' => true, 'secure' => true, 'samesite' => 'None'`
  in _csrf param for request block and _identity cookie in the user block

Using this you would be able to log into the domain1.com and domain2.com using same session on both the domains if the site is in iframe in the domain1.com

Answer (score 0):

For the PHP version < 7.3, Update the main.php config file and set the value of sameSite to None in variable path as
- cookie

```
    identityCookie' => [
           'name' => 'your_cookie_name',
           'httpOnly' => true
           'path' => '/;SameSite=None',
           'secure' => true
       ]
    
- session-cookie  

    'cookieParams' => [
      'lifetime' => time()*60,
      'httpOnly' => true,
      'secure'=>true,
      'path' => '/;SameSite=None'
    ]
```

Note:

1. You may need to edit the file: yii\web\Cookie, by updating the value
   of $path from '/' to '/;SameSite=None'.
2. PHP 7.3 and YII 2.0.21 comes with the solution of SameSite with 3
   values Lax,Strict and None. Click [here to know more](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-cookie).